# UI Path Studio package updates

Tags: automation

I am trying to update some packages in UI Path Studio and am getting errors.
Backstory:
Studio is installed on a VM in our Citrix environment.

Error message:
NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: The feed 'https://www.myget.org/F/workflow [https://www.myget.org/F/workflow]' lists package 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.6.12.2' but multiple attempts to download the nupkg have failed. The feed is either invalid or required packages were removed while the current operation was in progress. Verify the package exists on the feed and try again.
---> NuGet.Protocol.PackageNotFoundProtocolException: Unable to find package 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.6.12.2'.

I am able to brows to myget.org and find the package that I need however when I place the file in the C:\Program Files\UiPath\Studio\Packages folder i get the following error
The SSL connection could not be established
Unable to read the data from the transport connection : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host...